# Angular2 + FOREX Market Chart + Real data

Tags: angular, charts, forex

I want to draw a candlestick chart in angular2/4 with a real FOREX market chart.

But, currently I don't know where I can get real data.

Comment: While the Moshe's direction may help you to paint on screen, the main goal is in having live-FX-DataFeed and real-time update working. Both doable inside .js -- using messaging frameworks like a nanomsg or ZeroMQ ( guess both have language bindings for using them ). Next come the FX-DataFeed. Not speaking about licensing and legal terms and conditions, yet, there are plenty tools available from FOREX Brokers, that one may integrate wiht ( again, using ZeroMQ or nanomsg ). So, just your imagination + perseverance are your limits. Good Luck & Happy Trading. Feel free to read ZeroMQ posts on this

Comment: @user3666197 Thanks. Want to confirm: I will use an setInterval function to   access api to get real time data, then push and pull, right?

Comment: Well, not exactly. Your localhost event-loop is not the right even-source for processing an external real-time DataFeed, which has trigger-logic outside of your control. Principal rules are in control theory and technical cybernetics may help you, if you will, to correctly align event-processing. Again, don't get afraid to create multi-level distributed processing system, just take due care, who is event-source, who is even-collector and what are your event-processing policies for coping with your "enemies" ( transport-delay + other sources of event-processing latency ). Interesting&Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

look into the library D3JS, they have a candlestick chart.

Here's the "hello world" version of using D3 with Angular 5.

Once you get the gist, read this example (not angular), abstract the concept from "hello world", and follow suit:
http://bl.ocks.org/andredumas/27c4a333b0e0813e093d

The real data will come from a 3rd Party forex API, which probably has a websocket for each currency pair which pushes new data in real time. This could cost you.